# Providing wildcard mask in extended ACL

Tags: cisco, acl

Is it necessary to provide a wildcard mask in extended ACL?

For example, if I want to block 192.168.5.2 from gaining access to 192.168.7.2, can I write the command as follows?

```
access-list 107 deny 192.168.5.2 192.168.7.2
acess-list 107 permit any any
int fa 0/0
ip access-group in
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong.

The correct syntax is:

```
access-list 107 deny ip 192.168.5.2 0.0.0.0 host 192.168.7.2
access-list 107 permit ip any any

int fa 0/0
ip access-group 107 in
```

`0.0.0.0` is the ACL wildcard of `255.255.255.255` which is a single host (/32). `0.0.0.255` is the ACL wildcard of `255.255.255.0` which is a whole /24 subnet.

Comment: One thing that s confusing me is that when to use 0.0.0.0 and when to use 0.0.0.255 as wildcard mask?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 when there is host. 0.0.0.255 when subnet is /24

Comment: @AhmadQayyum check my updated answer. :-)

Comment: so if we want to deny a single host, we use 0.0.0.0 but if we want to deny a whole network, we use 0.0.0.255??

Comment: @AhmadQayyum yes exactly.

Comment: your "equivalent" is a bit ambiguous - you should note that 0.0.0.0 is the *ACL wildcard* for the precise host address = /32 netmask, and 0.0.0.255 is the wildcard for a /24 netmask.

Comment: @Zac67 you are correct, i've changed the text.

Answer (score 4):

ACLs use wildcards. You need to use e.g.

```
ip access-list 107 deny ip 192.168.5.2/32 192.168.7.2/32
```

The `/32` is equivalent to the `0.0.0.0` wildcard = no wildcard bits. Alternatively, you can use the `host` indicator, so `192.168.5.2/32`, `192.168.5.2 0.0.0.0`, and `host 192.168.5.2` are all the same. `any` is equivalent to `0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255` = all wildcard bits = any IP address.

Additionally, you should consider numbering your ACL entries to simplify future expansion, e.g.

```
ip access-list extended 107
10 deny ip 192.168.5.2/32 192.168.7.2/32
9999 permit any any
end
```

Comment: On all the routers i have available, Cisco 6509-E with Sup2T, Cisco 897, Cisco 3650/3850 etc. I do not have the command `access-list extended`. Only numbers are available that represent the extended, standard, protocol etc. All are running the latest Safe harbor software.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean `ip access-list extended 107`

Comment: @user56700 Thx, the `ip` was missing. The syntax does vary a bit but with the `ip` bit that should work.